# Visual Studio 2019 (vb) - issue with Reading/Writing My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

I'm just starting to develop and so there are some concepts that are not clear to me, I need you to try to understand what I'm doing wrong.

My goal is to have a series of `ComboBoxes` that contain some strings, for example a string is this one, the `ComboBox` is called `TYPE`:

[image: ComboboxTYPE]

I am storing these strings in `My.Settings` for my convenience and to edit them directly from the `app.exe.config` file (these information are stored there right?).

I'm using this code

```
Private Sub AdminPanel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each item In My.Settings.TYPE
            ComboBoxType.Items.Add(item)
        Next
End Sub
```

My issue is that, I'm unable to read from `My.Settings.TYPE` and when I try to write into it with the following code I doesn't find any strings added into `My.Settings` menu neither into `app.exe.config`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonTYPEAddValue.Click
        ComboBoxType.Items.Add(TextBoxType.Text)
        ComboBoxType.Text = TextBoxType.Text
        TextBoxType.Clear()
        MsgBox("Item added!")
End Sub
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, it seems like you've used `String` to add/remove the `ComboBoxType` items. Follow the steps to achieve your requirement:

In this screenshot, you can see I've set the Type as `System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection` to separate each time for future use.

[image: Items Collection]

Now, you may use the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Settings.tests.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    My.Settings.Save()
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub AdminPanel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each item In My.Settings.tests
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    My.Settings.tests.Remove(TextBox1.Text)
    My.Settings.Save()
    ComboBox1.Items.Remove(TextBox1.Text)
End
```

> It's noticeable that you can change the variable names, they're differ a bit than yours in my code.

Form structure for the code:

[image: Default form]

On the `MyBase.Load` event, all the items containing in `My.Settings.tests` will be added using `For Each` loop (benefit of StringCollection).

Working example of the form [adding - removing using My.Settings]:

[image: Adding to menu]         [image: Removing from menu]

I hope you've got your answer.

Comment: But you can see in the example, I've explicitly provided test strings collection in the 1st image + that's loaded on MyBase.Load event too.

Comment: Ok, undestood. But why I doesn't see changes done into application reflected on exe.config file? I see only original entries and not added

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYkBL.png

Comment: Make sure the settings are saved (try reopening the program and see whether it prints saved settings or not).

Comment: it's really unbelievable... so:

- into app.config in have these three strings ---
                        <string>INC</string>
                        <string>SR</string>
                        <string>CICCIO</string> ---
I added again this code on myBase.Load
        --- For Each item In My.Settings.TYPE
            ComboBoxTYPE.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End Sub ----
Result is that combobox doesn't contains entries present on my settings. If I add a new string into my combobox with code you provided me these changes are not reflected into app.config file. I'm desperate!

Comment: Try to delete the `app.config` and see if it works. The code is full working on my machine. It means you're almost succeeded, just something's wrong which is unknown.